# java : Different ways for constructing an ArrayList

Tags: java, web-services

I have developed a WebService which will be accessed by 1000's of users at a time  , as it is being a Financial Application .
Inside the code , I have created a ArrayList as shown

```
List Items = new ArrayList();
```

From the code point of view , i am parsing an XML File using STAX parser , Parsing XML , constructing Objects from XML and putting it into this ArrayList (Items)  .

And finally I am setting this ArrayList  inside a Request Object and using it .

All this is working fine , now my question is , what if i construct an ThreadSafe ArrayList this way and use this

```
List Items  = (List) Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
```

Please tell me if there would be any difference from performance point of view or in any case ?? Which is the best approach

Please share your experience and views .

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need synchronized `List` ?

Comment: Please follow naming conventions. Change your variable name to `items`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in creating a synchronized list if the list doesn't need to be synchronized. And if it needs to be synchronized, then performance doesn't matter, because it's preferrable to have a slower, correct program, than a faster, incorrect one.

You don't choose to use a synchronized list based on performance considerations. You choose it based on correctness considerations in a concurrent environment.

And if you have thread-safety problems, it's not by adding some synchronization randomly that it will work better. You have to understand how this all works. Read (at least) the [Java tutorial about concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Answer (score 0):

Given you are parsing XML, which is *very* heavy on CPU and memory, it wouldn't matter much what collection you used - it will make no measurable difference in performance